# which password to use for DocuSign API with SSO enabled

Tags: api, passwords, single-sign-on, docusignapi

With SSO enabled, each user's password is managed by the company AD server. Applications usually do not have password information. To make a DocuSign API call, username, password and IngratorKey are required. How do I make API call from the applications without the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your account is SSO enabled and you want to use the API. You will want to exempt one of your user's from SSO, to generate a password. API calls authenticate from this user and use Send on Behalf of for the other user's on the account that do not have passwords.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. More questions. Are you saying that I can use one user account to get data of other users and execute DocuSign actions on behalf for the other users? Does this "one user" have to be an administer or any special account?

Comment: Yes that is exactly correct. They need to have "Account Wide Access". See page 22 here: https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf#page=22

Comment: No problem, if this solved your question. Please accept it as an answer so others can benefit from this information.

Comment: Did not work yesterday from my PHP code. Will continue to try if I can find a time today. It would be great if the document had a workable PHP sample program.

Comment: there are code snippets that give examples in PHP here: http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs

Comment: I have a working php code with this:        $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>"; But if I change the above to:         $header = "<SendOnBehalfOf>xxxx@yahoo.com</SendOnBehalfOf><DocuSignCredentials><Username>"
 . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>"; The php code does not work, the return error is 401.

Comment: the SendOnBehalfOf node goes inside the DocuSignCredentials node.$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey><SendOnBehalfOf>xxxx@yahoo.com</SendOnBehalfOf></DocuSignCredentials>"